Redirigir dominio a subdominio manteniendo estructura de la URL
me estoy volviendo loco por alguna chorrada y no encuentro el fallo.
quiero redirigir las peticiones q vayan a dominio.es/web/unmontondecosas a subdominio.elmismodominio.es/web/elmismomontondecosas
He hecho este código pero me redirige la web entera!
'''
Options +FollowSymlinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

# http
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.es\web\$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://sub.dominio.es/web/$1 [R=301,L]

# https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.\web\es$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} =443
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sub.dominio.es/web/$1 [R=301,L]

''''

No se a que te refieres con la web entera, pero ojito con las peticiones 301, pues se almacenan en el cache de tu navegador, y si ya tenias alguna almacenada anteriormente, es probable que sea ejecutada pasando de lo que diga el .htaccess remodificado.  Quizás la mejor forma de comprobar si funciona la nueva redirección 301 que hayas puesto es con "wget" o "curl" desde terminal para ver donde lo reenvia. O bien borras el caché de tu navegador (aunque creo que segun sea el que uses necesitaras borrar más cosas)

pues q en vez de redigiri SOLO dominio.es/web/elchorro a subdominio.es/web/elchorro, redirige todo el dominio al subdominio.
No tengo problemas de cache.

¿puedes probar con wget o curl desde un terminal?  Así verás los pasos que va haciendo y si hace el 301 justo al entrar o quizás lo has puesto dentro de la configuración de tu wordpress de algun modo y se ejecuta después del index.php.  Aparte de eso, veo errores tipograficos aquí: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.es\web\$ [NC] y aquí RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?dominio\.\web\es$ [NC] pues diria que tienes mal algunas barras inclinadas revertidas y el orden del web y el es en la segunda

no sé mucho de regex, la idea es q dominio.es/web/loquesea vaya a subdominio.dominio.es/web/loquesea. Mantener el final de la URL y redireccionar solo las url q tengan /web/

He llegado a este codigo
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dominio.es$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^web(/|#)(.*)$ http://sub.dominio.es/web$1$2 [R=301,L,NE]
pero las urls mas complejas tipo web#etc no me las redirije bien

sabes q pasa? creo q ya lo se. si la url no lleva # redirige perfecto, pero en cuanto la lleva, no lo toma como parametro, sino como ancla, pq lo maneja el  navegador y creo q no se puede hacer desde htaccess

La razón por la que la redirección con /web# puede no estar funcionando es debido a cómo los navegadores manejan los fragmentos de URL, también conocidos como "anclas" (la parte de la URL después del #).
Cuando un navegador hace una solicitud a un servidor, no incluye el fragmento de la URL en la solicitud. Esto significa que el servidor no tiene conocimiento de la parte # de la URL, y por lo tanto no puede redirigir en base a ella.
En otras palabras, si tienes una URL como dominio.es/web#section1, el servidor solo ve dominio.es/web en la solicitud. El fragmento #section1 es manejado completamente por el navegador y no se envía al servidor.
Por lo tanto, no puedes hacer una redirección basada en el fragmento de la URL usando .htaccess o cualquier otra configuración del lado del servidor. Necesitarías manejar esto en el lado del cliente, posiblemente con JavaScript.
Si necesitas redirigir basándote en el fragmento de la URL, podrías considerar cambiar tu esquema de URL para usar rutas en lugar de fragmentos, por ejemplo, cambiando dominio.es/web#section1 a dominio.es/web/section1. Esto permitiría al servidor ver y redirigir basándose en la parte completa de la URL.
Al final lo he hecho con una redirección en el functions.php:
function redirigir_url_web_almohadilla() {
    $request_uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
    $host = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];

    if (strpos($request_uri, '/web#') || strpos($request_uri, '/web') === 0) {
        $new_url = 'URLNUEVA' . $request_uri;
        wp_redirect($new_url, 301);
        exit;
    }
}
add_action('init', 'redirigir_url_web_almohadilla');

